# Jaxb marshall abstract class instead of unique

Tags: java, jaxb

I have the following relation:

```
Class A abstract;
Class B concrete extends A;
Class C has a one to one relation with B.
```

let us say

```
A a=new B();
```

if i marshal A it will be marshalled by the use of the xml data presented on B

```
<B>
</B>
```

but if we say

```
C c = new C();
c.setA(new B());.
```

i get:

```
<C>
<A>
</A>
</C>
```

but A is abstract so during unmarshalling an exception will be thrown. my problem how to let jaxb marshell the concrete instead of abstract class during the marshalling of C so the result of the xml file wil be:

```
<C>
<B>
</B>
<C>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you annotate with `@XmlElementRef` then it will match the value based on its `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

```
@XmlElementRef
private A a;
```

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to annote the Clacc C in this way

```
public class C{

@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name="B", type=B.class),
    @XmlElement(name="D", type=D.class),
    @XmlElement(name="E", type=E.class),
    @XmlElement(name="F", type=F.class),
    //....
   })    
  private A a;


 }
```

Comment: problem is that A has 23 different implementation,  the problem may be that i am using A.getClass to create the jaxbContext i will try to us the packages that contain the concrete class.